# Getting error " MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not enough arguments for format string" while importing data

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have written the following code to import CSV data into mysql DB via python. But am getting the following error "MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not enough arguments for format string"

I have tried the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
import MySQLdb
df = pd.read_csv('D:\\UofG\\orders.csv',  sep='|', index_col=False)
print(df)

database = MySQLdb.connect (host="localhost", user="root", passwd="050194.Piku", db = "lineitem")
cursor = database.cursor()

for row in df:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ORDER_TABLE (O_ORDERKEY, O_CUSTKEY, O_ORDERSTATUS, O_TOTALPRICE, O_ORDERDATE, O_ORDERPRIORITY, O_CLERK, O_SHIPPRIORITY, O_COMMENT) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')", row)

cursor.close()

print ("COMPLETE")
```

The Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 201, in execute
    query = query % args
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/NewDB/read_data.py", line 10, in <module>
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ORDER_TABLE (O_ORDERKEY, O_CUSTKEY, O_ORDERSTATUS, O_TOTALPRICE, O_ORDERDATE, O_ORDERPRIORITY, O_CLERK, O_SHIPPRIORITY, O_COMMENT) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')", row)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 203, in execute
    raise ProgrammingError(str(m))
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Comment: `for row in df` does not do what you think it does. You should start by investigating what that actually gives.

Answer (score 0):

The line `for row in df:` does NOT iterate over the rows like you intended, it rather iterates over the column names (`row` will be of type `str` and hold the name of a column in this case).

Rather look into the methods [`.iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html), [`.itertuples()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) or [`.iteritems()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iteritems.html).

For example (code from the docs I linked above):

```
for label, content in df.iteritems():
    print('label:', label)
    print('content:', content)
```

Here is a related question about it: [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Comment: my CSV doesn't have any headers, and i am trying to import the data that i have in that file into an existing MySQL table. Can you give me any suggestions? I have modified the code to:import pandas as pd
import MySQLdb
df = pd.read_csv('D:\\UofG\\orders.csv',  sep='|', index_col=False)
#print(df)

database = MySQLdb.connect (host="localhost", user="root", passwd="050194.Piku", db = "lineitem")
cursor = database.cursor()

df.to_sql(con=database, name='ORDER_TABLE', if_exists='append')
database.commit()
cursor.close()

print ("COMPLETE")

Comment: But i get this error: "pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': not all arguments converted during bytes formatting"